# Use debugging for add action events

Tags: theme-development, actions

Is it possible to vardump the variable inside the action function? i am not able to echo or see results when i am doing so.

This is not a woo commerce question but i am having problems with

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed','wc_order_uppdate_to_cancelled_status', 20, 4);
```

Comment: Where is the `var_dump` in this? To be honest I don't really understand your question. You can use `var_dump()` inside the function that is called from that action, yes

Comment: @kero yes, that question was whether i can use var_dump()  inside the function that is called from that action..i am changing the order status from the backend for above function but does not show the any var_dump values...may be it is effecting the users only..nothing in admin side ..thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use debugging from an action where you won't see the output, you can send things to `error_log`. First, you need to enable debug logging. In your `/wp-config.php` add the lines:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

This will create a file called `/wp-content/debug.log`

Next, in your code, add some calls to `error_log` and [`var_export`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php):

```
add_action( 'init', 'some_function' );

function some_function( $var ) {
    error_log( var_export( $var, 1 ) );
}
```

Now, when `init` runs our function, the contents of `$var` will be dumped to `/wp-content/debug.log`. Note the second parameter to `var_export` says to return the output instead of trying to send it to be displayed.

#### Edit: 2021/09/17

Lately I've been using [Ray](https://spatie.be/docs/ray/v1/introduction) for debugging things in general, and it's particularly helpful when you can't see the output of the script you're running readily.

##### Installation

- Download the Ray app
- Install the package (they have a WordPress-specific plugin, I tend to just use the package directly)

```sh
composer require spatie/ray --dev
```

##### Usage

- Open the Ray app
- In your PHP, call `ray()`, e.g.

```php
ray($var);
```

The Ray window will populate with the variable's information:

[image: Ray window showing a Laravel exception]

Comment: thank you exactly what i was looking for..if my question is confusing and if can be improved please feel free to do so.

Comment: hi, ` error_log( var_export( $var, 1 ) );` what is parameter 1 in this code?

Comment: See the second parameter to `var_export` on [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). When the second parameter is truthy (e.g. `1`, `true`, etc), `var_export` will return it's output instead of just dumping it to the screen.